I have created a bean of PasswordEncoder type but still my springboot app is showing me that i don't have any such bean
I am working on a spring boot application. where I have created a bean of type PasswordEncoder but when I run the code it shows me the following error
Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in
com.example.FintechBackend.service.UserService
required a bean of type
'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder'
that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type
'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' in
your configuration.

While I have already declared the bean in the configuration file but still I am getting this error. I ma confused that how to resolve it
following are my classes
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
    
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    
    
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
    
            try {
                return http
                        .authorizeHttpRequests(authCustomizer -> authCustomizer
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,
                                        "/api/users/register", "/api/users/login").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/users/{id}").hasRole("USER")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/users/{id}").hasRole("USER")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/users/{id}").hasRole("USER")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/transactions").hasRole("USER")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/transactions/{id}").hasRole("USER")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/transactions/{id}").hasRole("USER")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/transactions/{id}").hasRole("USER")
                        )
                        .build();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

The BCryptPasswordEncoder created in configuration class is used in Userservice, whose code is as following
    import com.example.FintechBackendDeveloperAssignment.DTO.UserRegistrationDTO;
    import com.example.FintechBackendDeveloperAssignment.model.User;
    import com.example.FintechBackendDeveloperAssignment.repository.UserRepository;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    
    @Service
    public class UserService {
        private final UserRepository userRepository;
        private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
        private final Logger logger;
    
        public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, Logger logger) {
            this.userRepository = userRepository;
            this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
            this.logger = logger;
        }
    
        public User registerUser(UserRegistrationDTO registrationDTO) {
            User existingUser = userRepository.findByEmail(registrationDTO.getEmail());
            if (existingUser != null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Email already exists");
            }
    
            User user = new User();
            user.setName(registrationDTO.getName());
            user.setEmail(registrationDTO.getEmail());
            user.setRole("USER");
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registrationDTO.getPassword()));
            userRepository.save(user);
    
            logger.info("User registered: " + user.getEmail());
    
            return user;
        }
    
        public User loginUser(String email, String password) {
            User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
            if (user == null || !passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid email or password");
            }
    
            logger.info("User logged in: " + user.getEmail());
    
            return user;
        }
    }

We are creating the object of this userservice in our controller and here is the place from where it throws the error
import com.example.FintechBackendDeveloperAssignment.DTO.UserRegistrationDTO;
import com.example.FintechBackendDeveloperAssignment.model.Transaction;
import com.example.FintechBackendDeveloperAssignment.model.User;
import com.example.FintechBackendDeveloperAssignment.service.UserService;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Content;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponses;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {
    private final UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Tag(name = "post", description = "Post methods of user APIs")
    @Operation(summary = "Register User",
            description = "This APi is use to register new user in system")
    @ApiResponses({
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", content = { @Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                    schema = @Schema(implementation = User.class)) }),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "User not created",
                    content = @Content) })
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserRegistrationDTO registrationDTO, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Validation errors");
        }

        try {
            User user = userService.registerUser(registrationDTO);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(user);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Operation(summary = "Login User",
            description = "This API is use to Login user in system")
    @ApiResponses({
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", content = { @Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                    schema = @Schema(implementation = User.class)) }),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "User not LoggedIn",
                    content = @Content) })
    @Tag(name = "post", description = "Post methods of user APIs")
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> loginUser(@RequestParam String email, @RequestParam String password) {
        try {
            User user = userService.loginUser(email, password);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

While following is the structure of my code.


Try changing the type of the password encoder in your service constructor to match the type of bean you are creating:
public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, Logger logger)

The problem is that even though the implementations are both BCryptPasswordEncoder, the bean you're creating is registered with Spring as the interface type PasswordEncoder and spring is looking for an autowire candidate of the more specific implementation type BCryptPasswordEncoder.
Also, change the type of the passwordEncoder field in your service to match.
